# Get result of first task in group of tasks (celery)

Tags: python, celery

How to get result of first task in group?

I'm using this way -

```
res = chain.delay()
first_task = res.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.collect()
```

But it's super ugly, is there any another more beautiful way?

Comment: can you share `chain`'s assignment?

Comment: chain = (       create_task.s()        | create_task_1.s()     | create_task_2.s() | create_task_3.s() )

something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not that much more elegant, you can genericize by using a `while` loop:

```
def first_result(res):
    r = res
    while r.parent:
        r = r.parent
    return r.result()
```